# xsl:choose save as variable

Tags: performance, xslt

I am busy trying to get my xsl as performant as possible. So here is what i have.

```
<xsl:when test=".//div[starts-with(@class,'ls-col ') or @class='ls-col']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//div[starts-with(@class,'ls-col ') or @class='ls-col']" mode="col"/>
</xsl:when>`
```

So the logic here is if the div with ls-col exist apply the template with mode="col".

So i was thinking the way this looks to me is that it will evaluate  this twice

```
.//div[starts-with(@class,'ls-col ') or @class='ls-col']
```

Is there a way to save this and just use it in the apply template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim C says, if it was an xsl:if you could just rely on the apply-templates doing nothing when the condition isn't true. But if there's an 'otherwise' branch, just put the condition in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="c" select=".//div[starts-with(@class,'ls-col ') or @class='ls-col']"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$c">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$c" mode="col"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the the **xsl:when** in this case. Just do the **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select=".//div[starts-with(@class,'ls-col ') or @class='ls-col']" mode="col"/>
```

If there are no **div** tags that match, then the **xsl:apply-templates** will not match anything, and so nothing will be output at this point. Therefore there is no reason to check for the existence of such tags beforehand.

Comment: Hi. There is another part to the choose so if there is no div class="lscol" it applies another template.